# R How Do I replace values in a DataSet with matching values from a different level data set

Tags: r

Given two data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(letters = c("A","B","3","D","5","G"),numbers = c(1:6))
df2 = data.frame(letters = c("C","E"), numbers = c(3,5))

df1
# letters   numbers
#    A         1
#    B         2
#    3         3
#    D         4
#    5         5
#    F         6 
df2
# letters   numbers
#    C         3
#    E         5
```

What do I need to do that at the end i get this data frame.

```
finalData

# letters   numbers
#    A         1
#    B         2
#    C         3
#    D         4
#    E         5
#    F         6
```

I tried so inner_join but I didnt manage to get the desired result. Please let me know which function to use! So I can take the next step. Thank you!

Comment: One option using `match`: `df1$letters[match(df2$numbers, df1$letters)] <- df2$letters` But make sure you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (works with `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` or `FALSE`)

```
# rbind matched values in df2 with df1 (without the rows corresponding to matches)
df <- rbind(df1[!df1$letters %in% df2$numbers,],df2[df2$numbers %in% df1$letters,])
df <- df[order(df$numbers),] # order the data frame
df
#    letters numbers
# 1        A       1
# 2        B       2
# 11       C       3
# 4        D       4
# 21       E       5
# 6        F       6
```

with the data

```
df1 <- data.frame(letters = c("A","B","3","D","5","F"),numbers = c(1:6)) # changed G to F
df2 <- data.frame(letters = c("C","E"), numbers = c(3,5))
```